# Excel Add a variable to module permanently if it is found in spreadsheet at a location

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, module, save

The simple question is how do I save add a variable to my module permanently for further use?

Here's the detailed version:

I'm making a macro that parses trade transactions and my input file has account numbers that needs to be translated into portfolio names in the result file.

Currently I maintain two arrays, one for the account number, and another for its name. e.g:
arr1, arr2

> 1111, FIRST_PORTFOLIO ... 9999, LAST_PORTFOLIO

And there's a little function that matches account numbers and if found it returns the portfolio name at the same index.

If this function finds a portfolio number that's not in the array it returns BLANK. But I would like to add this number and its name to arr1 and arr2 permanently so next time when someone uses the macro the account would be registered.

This is for my coworkers that don't program so I need to do give them instruction for something that can just be done in Excel's frontend.

I'm thinking to just let excel check on X1 and Z1 (and rows down if there are multiple accounts need to be added), and if not empty append these values to my array.

Question is once this is done, can it be saved to the arrays permanently so they will be in my module permanently? i.e. if I have 5 entries in arr1 and arr2 now and I add 2 to arr1 and arr2, how can I have a 7-entry array ready for use when I run my macro on a different file in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: This type of thing is best handled using vlookup against a hidden sheet: you could give your users a way to add entries to that range (using a couple of Input or a custom form)

Comment: problem is we get a report xls file sent from other managers and hence adding another sheet would be much less efficient

Comment: Are your macros in the same file as the data, or in a standalone file? How are you "maintaining" your lookup array - are they hard-coded or are they read off a worksheet?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for better implementation Tim but I'm not looking for a workaround right now. The arrays are hardcoded into macros saved in an XLAM file. I'm asking if there's a way to track whether if some two cells are populated and if they are redim the array and append these elements to their respective array, and make this change permanent.

Comment: Don't know that much about Excel but seems like what I want is pretty undoable. My feeling is that there isn't a vb function that would "type new lines" for me in my module's code and save it.

Comment: You can use VBA to write to a VB Project (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx), but it isn't a great idea to re-write code in the currently-running workbook: it would likely cause a recompile, and you'd loose any existing variable state. Even if you're using an add-in, it can still have a worksheet with data in it...